# Alterar valor de data=" " de tooltips caso sejam exibidos em resolução menor que 767px?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou implementando alguns ***tooltips*** em um formulário de contato que estou desenvolvendo. Acontece que quando é carregado em resolução menor (abaixo de 767px), fica cortado os ***tooltips***. Isso se deve ao fato dos ***tooltips*** ter tido a direção deles setada pelo `data-mytooltip-direction="right"`. Observem que está setado **"right"** que significa (**direita**) em Português.

---

> Como fazer para que abaixo de (767px) o `data-mytooltip-direction="right"` mude de **"right"** para **"bottom"** ?

#### Exemplo:

`<input class="form-control validation js-mytooltip" data-mytooltip-custom-class="align-center" data-mytooltip-direction="right" data-mytooltip-theme="light" data-mytooltip-content="O e-mail é importante para o acompanhamento" id="texto" name="email" type="text" data-email="Email inválido" data-required="Campo obrigatório">`

> Como fazer isto funcionar?

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois já mudou demais o sentido dela depois de respondida. O ideal é fazer a pergunta com todos os detalhes desde o começo, e no máximo complementar. Mudar a natureza, não. E você faz isso com uma certa frequência.

Comment: É a única solução que vejo @Bacco via `PHP`, pois via `Javascript` não vai ser possível :( Vou fazer o que então? Outra pergunta?

Comment: O que vai fazer, não sei, só estou explicando o que não pode fazer. Pode perguntar à vontade dentro das regras do site, mas não adianta esperar que te entreguem o serviço pronto nos mínimos detalhes e ir mexendo a pergunta até conseguir isso depois de respondida. Já respondi uma vez, complementei com um Codepen do segundo caso, que nem na pergunta estava, e tudo funciona perfeitamente. E agora você quer mudar a linguagem? Não é razoável usar o site desta forma. O site está aqui para ser usado, mas já elabore a pergunta com tudo que precisar desde o começo.

Comment: Citei `PHP` como uma melhor opção, ou seja via `Javascript` ou `PHP`. Javascript acho meio improvável. Quando você diz "O ideal é fazer a pergunta com todos os detalhes desde o começo", acontece que a gente só vai saber testando, aí depois a pessoa pode querer mudar alguma coisa, pois agora sabemos que há coisas que não poderão ser feitas. Aí é por isso que as vezes mudamos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Com uma função bem simples dá para resolver isso:

```
function adjustTooltipOrientation(el) {
    var target = document.getElementById(el);
    var orientation = window.innerWidth<767 ? 'bottom' : 'right';
    target.dataset.mytooltipDirection=orientation;
}
```

Para usar, basta chamar desta forma:

```
adjustTooltipOrientation('id-da-div-desejada');
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/ALNaNG)**

Note que **para simplificar o teste**, usamos o `content` do CSS para mostrar o valor do atributo. Só browsers modernos reconhecem este atributo, portanto, recomendo testar num Opera ou Firefox recente (acredito que no Chrome também funcione). Esta restrição do teste **não interfere** na aplicação real do código.

#### Usando com `class`:

Como já dito nos comentários, se quiser usar com classe (o que não está na pergunta), pode alterar a função para agir sobre o elemento, em vez do `id`:

```
function adjustTooltipOrientation(target) {
    var orientation = window.innerWidth<767 ? 'bottom' : 'right';
    target.dataset.mytooltipDirection=orientation;
}
```

Aí basta usar um

```
var l = document.getElementsByClassName('classe');
for (var i=0; i<l.length; i++) adjustTooltipOrientation(l[i]);
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/LRobGP)**

Note que o uso é um exemplo, **você tem que ajustar para a realidade da sua página**.

Você pode chamar esta função na carga da página, e para uma melhor experiência, no evento de *resize*.

Comment: Olá Bacco, só teve um probleminha, seu exemplo é com uma **DIV**, e no caso necessita que seja feita em várias **INPUT's** :/ Acho que `class=" "` seria o ideal :/

Comment: Respondi a pergunta com base no que você colocou nela, um input, mas não faz diferença, como é uma função, você pode chamar para todos os elementos que quiser, tranquilamente. O importante é entender a lógica, e ajustar para o seu caso. Se preferir fazer um loop por class. ela também funciona numa boa, só ajuste o getElementById.

Comment: Bacco, desculpa ai minha falta de conhecimento, rsrs, mas como faço para colocar pra funcionar em vários `INPUT's` ? Ficou perfeito seu exemplo :3

Comment: Alexandre Lopes, No lugar de `document.getElementById(el);`, apenas coloque `document.getElementsByClassName(el);`. Você não deixou claro na pergunta sobre essa "condição". Ele apresentou uma resposta genérica. Adapte-a conforme o seu caso. Ainda terá que fazer um laço de repetição `for () {` iterando os elementos.

Comment: Bacco, tem como você criar um CodePen no exemplo utilizando `class`? Tentei aqui e está dando erro :/

Comment: @Bacco .......?

Comment: Pronto, revisado, testado e posto no codepen. Vou cuidar de outras coisas aqui, pq já fiquei muito tempo nessa postagem.

Comment: @Bacco continua sempre em `right`, não está mudando para `bottom`, acho que tem um probleminha no seu CodePen

Comment: Isso de mudar automático é só copiar do outro. Esse codepen é basicamente pra você ver como usar a função ajustada.

Comment: Ahh, agora entendi. Ele não muda de acordo com o que a página é redimensionada, e sim de acordo com o tamanho da tela que foi carregada.

Comment: Sim, mas para mudar automático é só fazer o que foi feito no outro codepen, colocar o loop dentro de um onResize. Bom, preciso ir, já atrasei aqui. Não era nem pra eu estar no site.

Comment: @Bacco não funcionou aqui. Eu atualizei a pergunta, dá uma olhadinha lá. `PHP` deve ser o ideal. :/

Answer (score 4):

Use o método "data()" para alterar o valor do atributo. Coloque dentro da chamada "ready()" no seu script. Se todo input com essa tooltip tiver como uma das classes de estilo a "js-mytooltip", esse comando será global, afetará todos as tooltips.

Usando teste e atribuição inline:

```
$(function() { //ready()
    $(".js-mytooltip").data("mytooltip-direction", ($(window).width() < 767) ? 'bottom' : 'right');
});
```

O mesmo código estendido:

```
$(function() { //ready()
    if($(window).width() < 767) {
        $(".js-mytooltip").data("mytooltip-direction", "bottom");
    } else {
        $(".js-mytooltip").data("mytooltip-direction", "right");
    }
});
```

Comment: Carlos, dá uma olhadinha na pergunta, eu editei. Não funcionou, justamente pelo fato que eu citei. Acho que `PHP` seria a melhor, ou única forma de fazer isto funcionar.

Comment: Javascript serve justamente para modificar uma página já carregada. Através do Javascript (de forma ainda mais fácil ainda se você estiver usando jQuery) você consegue acessar qualquer elemento e atributo de elemento no HTML. Uma pergunta, você está testando arrastando a tela ou já abrindo em uma janela pequena?

Comment: Se você está testando no Google Chrome, aperte F12 e veja as modificações acontecendo no DOM do seu HTML em tempo real. É diferente de verificar o código fonte, pois no F12 mostra a estrutura DOM que o browser está executando no momento e em tempo real. Por exemplo, se você der um document.write(<span>hello world</span>), você verá esse elemento aninhado dentro da estrutura do HTML, enquanto no código fonte você verá o comando script.

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar uma função auto executável que verifica todos os elementos com a classe `js=tooltip` e que execute a função principal no evento `resize` da janela.

Independentemente do usuário abrir em um desktop ou em um mobile o script será executado e re-executado no evento `resize`.

```js
// auto execute
;(function(){
    var init = function(){
        var get = document.getElementsByClassName('js-mytooltip');
        if(!!get){
           var i = get.length;
           for(;i--;){
               if( window.innerWidth < 767 && get[i].getAttribute('data-mytooltip-direction') ){
                   get[i].setAttribute('data-mytooltip-direction','bottom');
               }else{
                   get[i].setAttribute('data-mytooltip-direction','right')
               }
           }
        }
    };
    // initialize
    init();
    // listen event
    window.addEventListener('resize', init);
})();
```

```html
<span class="js-mytooltip" data-mytooltip-direction="right"></span>

<span class="js-mytooltip" data-mytooltip-direction="right"></span>

<span class="js-mytooltip" data-mytooltip-direction="botom"></span>

<!-- havendo classe mas não havendo data-, então sera criado -->
<span class="js-mytooltip" data-another="sort value"></span>

<span class="notooltip" data-mytooltip-direction="undefined"></span>
```